# SSO authentication for viewing a HTML page running on Apache Tomcat

Tags: java, javascript, html, tomcat, single-sign-on

We have a Web Application which have HTML 5  page to see the messages in realtime through websocket connection to our servers.Making websocket connection and showing the graphs work well,HTML5 page needs SSO authentication before it gets displayed.

**What has been completed**

> But for viewing that HTML 5 page we have no file based authentication to read the file with usernames and show a popup to enter username if it is matched then user will be able to see the HTML graphs page.This is not very good approach!!!

**What needs to be DONE**

> Now some type of SSO-Single Sign On authentication(**not sure on what type of authentication our organization is currently using**) is needed which will do some magical authentication on the back end and after that user would be able to see the HTML graphs page.

`Currently the application is running on Apache Tomcat 6 and have couple of javascript files,CSS and one HTML page.Potential solution should be implemented in JAVA,can use any 3rd party API too.`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Still waiting for help :(

Comment: What kind of SSO?  SSO implies that the user has authenticated via some external system (not your application) and then redirected to your app.  Is this what you mean?  If so, what is the external system?  What SSO protocols does it support?